# Adding smaller and smaller numbers-proof

Tags: summation

Equation that needs to be proved:
[image]

I didnt write from ... to ... on summation sign ( I didn't want to make a mistake), but i'll explain what is summation doing.
Example:  $r=10$ , $\Delta r$ is $0.1$ then we add: $10$ $+ (10-0.1)$ $+(10-2 \cdot 0.1)$ $+(10-3 \cdot 0.1)$ and we keep adding until $10-n \cdot 0.1$ is equal to $0$ ( We are actually adding this : $10+9.9+9.8+9.7+9.6+\cdots +0$).Then we multiply that sum with $\Delta r$ and the result should be close to $r^2/2$.
It should work for any $r$ and if $\Delta r$ is going to $0$ then the left part of equation will be equal to the right part. 
Is there a way of proving this or to disprove it. 
Thanks

Comment: Try it yourself with some examples that don't require so many terms. For example, try $r=2, \Delta r = 1.$ Then the sum is $2+1+0.$ Is the formula true? Remember that if you find one example that the formula says it should work for, and the formula is not correct for that example, then the formula is disproved. If you think you can fix the formula so that it works for this example, try it with a different $\Delta r,$ such as $\Delta r = \frac12.$

Comment: I already got a answer and i don't have a problem anymore.

Comment: I admit I missed some of the finer points of the question due to the awkward notation, but I see that someone apparently was able to understand the question you were trying to ask. If that answer has helped you, you might consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $\Delta r = r / n\,$, then the sum runs from $0$ to $n\,$, and the terms are in arithmetic progression:

$$\require{cancel}
\frac{r}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n}(r - k \frac{r}{n}) = \frac{r}{n} \left(r \sum_{k=0}^{n} 1 - \frac{r}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} k \right) = \frac{r^2}{n}\left(n - \frac{1}{\cancel{n}}\cdot \frac{\cancel{n}(n+1)}{2}\right) = \frac{r^2}{2} \cdot \frac{n-1}{n}
$$

For large enough $n\,$, the second factor $\,(n-1)/n = 1 - 1/n \,\simeq\, 1\,$.